# QS: Find the sheets that use the master item

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have many sheets in Qlik Sense and I need to modify the name of a master measure.

How can I find all sheets/visualizations where that master measure is used? So I know what will it affect.

Answer (score 0):

In the help of QLik (http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2017/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Assets/edit-master-measure.htm) you can see that if you change the name, that change will be aplied to all objects.

I supose that is impossible to know who object will be afected.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out the master measure then all the dependent visualizations across all sheets will show '-'. This way you know which measures/visuals are getting affecting.